# Getting error in phpmyadmin stored procedure script

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im creating a stored procedure in phpmyadmin, which get the event category list. The condition im using, im sending a parameter 'e_range' where i get the list on the basis of whatever i set the range on this parameter 3, 4 etc. but im getting an error in while executing this script: 
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'e_range; else select category_id, category_name, category_thumb from category' at line 4**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_category_list`(IN e_range int)
BEGIN
if(e_range != 0 or null) then
    select category_id, category_name, category_thumb from category_list order by category_name limit e_range;
else
    select category_id, category_name, category_thumb from category_list order by category_name;
END if;
END$$
```

**Now problem is that, this script working good in my localhost pc. but im getting these error on my webserver CPANEL's phpmyadmin.**
the MySQL keyword 'LIMIT' is not taking the value through parameter. or maybe not recognizing it. but when i remove this parameter from the select command and set the static number on this, it will work:

```
select category_id, category_name, category_thumb from category_list order by category_name limit 5;
```

now what is the procedure, so i will get the list through my given parameter.

Thank you :)

Comment: Bit rusty with MySQL SP's, but shouldn't the logic syntax be `iF(e_range != 0 or e_range IS NOT NULL) ... ` ?

Comment: lol my bad, i will change it....but give me the solution of this error :P